# Storing functions from class in array and invoke them c++

Tags: c++, class

i try store a functions(methods) from class in array and use them.
The error handle is

> In function 'int main()':|  'actions' was not declared in this
>   scope

this my code(i delete unnecessary code)
the class.h:

```
class Calculator
{
    public:
        int num1,num2;
        void (Calculator::*actions[4])();
        void  add();
        void  minuz();
        void  multi();
        void  div();
        Calculator();
};
```

class.cpp:

```
void  Calculator::add()
{}
void  Calculator::minuz()
{}
void  Calculator::div()
{ }
void Calculator::multi()
{}
Calculator::Calculator()
{
    actions[0]=add;
    actions[1]=minuz;
    actions[2]=div;
    actions[3]=multi;
}
```

main:

```
Calculator cal;
.....
.....
cal.*actions[num]();
```

Comment: You don't have a `actions` variable defined in your class.

Comment: Where have you defined `actions`?

Comment: in class.cpp it`s not the right way?

Comment: Most likely not. Although I don't understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: actions is my array of functions ,i store the functions there ,so where i need to declare ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ syntax for function pointer declaration is quite complicated, so it better use `typedefs`
To call function by pointer you need extra `()` around dereferenced function pointer.
Finally it will be:

```
class Calculator
{
    public:
        typedef void (Calculator::*action)();
        int num1,num2;
        action actions[4];
        void  add();
        void  minuz();
        void  multi();
        void  div();
        Calculator();
};

void  Calculator::add()
{}
void  Calculator::minuz()
{}
void  Calculator::div()
{ }
void Calculator::multi()
{}
Calculator::Calculator()
{
    actions[0]=&Calculator::add;
    actions[1]=&Calculator::minuz;
    actions[2]=&Calculator::div;
    actions[3]=&Calculator::multi;
}

int main(int, char**) {
    Calculator cal;
    int num = 0;
    (cal.*cal.actions[num])();
    return 0;
}
```

for better readability I'd suggest add function `Calculator::call_by_index(int)`:

```
void Calculator::call_by_index(int index)
{
    (this->*actions[index])();
}
```

and call it in such way:

```
cal.call_by_index(num);
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a typedef usually helps: (c++03)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0e79796cc55e822)</kbd>**

```
class Calculator
{
    public:
        int num1,num2;
        typedef void (Calculator::*Action)();
        Action actions[4];
        Calculator() {
            actions[0]=&Calculator::add;
            actions[1]=&Calculator::minuz;
            actions[2]=&Calculator::div;
            actions[3]=&Calculator::multi;
        }
    private:
        void add()   {}
        void minuz() {}
        void multi() {}
        void div()   {}
};

int main() {
    Calculator cal;
    (cal.*cal.actions[1])();
}
```

### C++11 aliases

C++11 makes it easier:

```
    using Action = void (Calculator::*)();
    Action actions[4];
```

> See also https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b974dbac0ee628c4)</kbd>**

### `std::function<>`

Also in c++11 (or boost if you want it in c++03):

```
    using Action = std::function<void(Calculator&)>;
    Action actions[4];
```

Which you would still call like

```
cal.actions[1](cal);
```

I'd pre-bind to the `Calculator` instance:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b2134254586a3246)</kbd>**

```
#include <functional>

class Calculator
{
    public:
        int num1,num2;
        using Action = std::function<void()>;
        Action actions[4];
        Calculator() {
            actions[0] = [this]() { add(); };
            actions[1] = [this]() { minuz(); };
            actions[2] = [this]() { multi(); };
            actions[3] = [this]() { div(); };
        }
    private:
        void add()   {}
        void minuz() {}
        void multi() {}
        void div()   {}
};

int main() {
    Calculator cal;
    cal.actions[1]();
}
```

Comment: Would be great if this answer could be extended with C++11 `using Action = void (Calculator::*)();`

Comment: @AMA Agreed. Went a few extra miles here :)

Comment: @sehe great answer! you forgot to change `typedef` to `using` in the second snippet though :)

Answer (score 4):

You're not calling it right.  Since `actions` is a member of `Calculator`, you need to reference a `Calculator` object to get at it.

```
(cal.*(cal.actions[num]))();
```

The first `cal` is the object you're wanting to call the action with, and the second `cal` is used to access the action you want to call.

Comment: You missed parentheses around `cal.*(cal.actions[num])` function pointer